# Force start page or single entry point

Tags: html

I have a web application that I want to force users to log in before they can get to any other pages. I have set up the login and it is working but I can't figure out how to stop them from by passing the login on subsequent visits.

for example they save a link to main.html so I haven't authenticated them. Ideas??

thanks John

Answer (score 0):

For authentication purposes, you should never really on client-side validation only.
Client-side, there's not really much you can do, as the user could just go in and change your code.

The correct way to handle this, is a server-side check (using PHP, ASP.NET, ...) combined with setting a cookie

Please let us know which technology you are using on the server-side (if any)